# An algorithmic adaptation of a lemma on maximization of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms

In complex analysis we have Jack's lemmma related to the maximum value of an analytic function in a domain. The lemma states:
**(Jack's Lemma)** Let $f(z)$ be a non-constant and holomorphic function in the unit disc $D$ with $f(0)=0$. If $|f(z)|$ attains its maximum value on the circle $|z|=r$ at the point $z_0$, then
$$
\frac{z_0 f^{\prime}\left(z_0\right)}{f\left(z_0\right)}=k
$$
where $k \geq 1$ is a real number.
For a given function say $\sin z+e^z-1$, I wonder If we vary $z_0$ along a unit circle, how can we computationally know if
$$\frac{z_0 f^{\prime}\left(z_0\right)}{f\left(z_0\right)}$$ is real or not.The thing is in any implementation of it in a computer language, we have to work with floating point arithmetic and we may never know if the said quantity is purely real. Or is there is way around? I would be highly obliged if somebody could kindly point out some resources / links which talk about it's implementaion.

Comment: Not to answer your question, just to point out that $f(z)=\sin z+e^z$ doesn't satisfy $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I was asking generally.And btw,we can define  $g(z)=f(z)-1$